# Python markdown displays list item (li) as h2 heading when at end of text and followed by line break and - sign

Tags: python, markdown

I am using the python markdown module to allow some markdown formatting of text input.

There is one case I can't figure out:

If I use a line break followed by one or more minus symbols "-", but no other symbols, the last line will be displayed as `<h2>` instead or additional to other styles. Happens at the end of unordered lists sometimes.

This is unexpected for me and I couldn't find something on it in the documentation. Is this correct?

```
import markdown
  

print(markdown.markdown("Why is this h2 and not p? \n-"))

# <h2>Why is this h2 and not p?</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [setext heading](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#setext-headings).

> A setext heading consists of one or more lines of text, not
> interrupted by a blank line, of which the first line does not have
> more than 3 spaces of indentation, followed by a setext heading
> underline. The lines of text must be such that, were they not followed
> by the setext heading underline, they would be interpreted as a
> paragraph: they cannot be interpretable as a code fence, ATX heading,
> block quote, thematic break, list item, or HTML block.
>
> A setext heading underline is a sequence of `=` characters or a sequence
> of `-` characters, with no more than 3 spaces of indentation and any
> number of trailing spaces or tabs. If a line containing a single `-` can
> be interpreted as an empty list items, it should be interpreted this
> way and not as a setext heading underline.
>
> The heading is a level 1 heading if `=` characters are used in the
> setext heading underline, and a level 2 heading if `-` characters are
> used. The contents of the heading are the result of parsing the
> preceding lines of text as CommonMark inline content.

Examples:

```markdown
Foo *bar*
=========

Foo *bar*
---------
```

```html
<h1>Foo <em>bar</em></h1>
<h2>Foo <em>bar</em></h2>
```

```markdown
Foo *bar
baz*
====
```

```html
<h1>Foo <em>bar
baz</em></h1>
```

And, as in your case, the underline can be any length (though SO's parser doesn't agree):

```markdown
Foo
-------------------------

Foo
=
```

```html
<h2>Foo</h2>
<h1>Foo</h1>
```